# what is the difference between uri and path?

Tags: theme-development

I am new in WordPress theme development and I've got a problem!
what is the difference between get_theme_file_path() and get_theme_file_uri()?
both of them return the same thing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `get_theme_file_uri` returns http url like

```
http://example.com/wp-content/theme/...
```

The function `get_theme_file_path` returns file system url to file as

```
/home/mysite/www/wp-content/theme/...
```